# Getting a single output from cfquery when query column is cfqueryparam variable

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfquery, cfqueryparam

I'm using ColdFusion and trying to make a function that will allow me to get the value of a specific column in a specific account (each account is its own record/row).

A function like this works fine:

```
<cffunction name="getColumnValueFromAccount" access="public" returntype="string" >
    <cfargument name="accountName" type="string" required="yes" />

    <cfquery name="getColumn" datasource="mydatasource">
        <!--- Note that the line below is 'hard-coded.' --->
        SELECT role_ExampleSystem
        FROM table_name
        WHERE (accountName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value='#accountName#'>)
    </cfquery>

    <!--- It's easy to return the column value when you know what its name was. --->
    <cfreturn getColumn.role_ExampleSystem > 

</cffunction>
```

But what I actually want is a function that allows me to specify which column name to read from, and eliminate the need for making a bunch of nearly identical CF functions that just have a different hard-coded SELECT parameter. I'm thinking it should look something like this, but I'm having trouble actually reading the single string that I believe it should be returning.

```
<cffunction name="getColumnValueFromAccount" access="public" returntype="string" >
    <cfargument name="accountName" type="string" required="yes" />
    <!--- Trying to accept a column name as an argument --->
    <cfargument name="columnName" type="string" required="yes" />

    <cfquery name="getColumn" datasource="mydatasource">
        <!--- I'm trying to use cfqueryparam to add specify the column name to select. --->
        SELECT <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value='#columnName#'>
        FROM table_name
        WHERE (accountName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value='#accountName#'>)
    </cfquery>

    <!--- This line doesn't work. --->
    <cfreturn getColumn[#columnName#] >

</cffunction>
```

I thought that you were able to use variables in a bracket notation like `getColumn[#columnName#]` or `getColumn[columnName]` because someone mentioned it in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1212554/can-i-get-a-query-row-by-index-in-coldfusion#comment1038224_1212664). But when I've tried to use variables myself it has not worked as expected. I get this error:

`The value returned from the getColumnValueFromAccount function is not of type string. If the component name is specified as a return type, it is possible that either a definition file for the component cannot be found or is not accessible.`

Any idea what route I should take when I want to get the single result of a cfquery, but I am not using a hard-coded column name in the SELECT part of my query? Normally this process is very simple, but it seems that when your column name is a variable things become a bit different.

Comment: *I'm trying to use cfqueryparam to add specify the column name to select.*  You can't do it that way.  CFQueryparam can only be used on literals, not on things that must be evaluated as sql commands - like table or column names.

Comment: That could be part of the problem, and technically I don't need the SQL injection protection cfqueryparam provides, because the cfargument for columnName will be something I specify in another server side function. No need to clean the input because I know it will be something valid I wrote.

Comment: I removed the `cfqueryparam` as you suggested and replaced with with a `#variable#` then used Mark A Kruger's corrected example of how to use bracket notation. It looks like it is working as expected! I'll post what I have in the end in case it helps people in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## My Solution:

Based on Leigh's advice that I can't use `cfqueryparam` in the way I was trying to use it, and Mark A Kruger's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36485510/3680712) I was able to modify my code and get it working. It now looks like this:

```
<cffunction name="getColumnValueFromAccount" access="public" returntype="string" >
    <cfargument name="accountName" type="string" required="yes" />
    <cfargument name="columnName" type="string" required="yes" />

    <cfquery name="getColumn" datasource="mydatasource">
        SELECT #columnName#
        FROM table_name
        WHERE (accountName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value='#accountName#'>)
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn getColumn[columnName][1] >

</cffunction>
```

It now correctly returns an account's role in a specified system i.e. if account `accountName` is an `admin` in `ExampleSystem` and I passed in `role_ExampleSystem` to the function as `ColumnName` the function will return `admin` as expected.

## Warning: My solution could present a SQL injection risk if used improperly!

Using a ColdFusion variable in a SQL statement like this doesn't provide any protection from SQL injection so it would be a ***very bad idea*** to allow a user to enter the data that is used for the `columnName` here. In my case this function will only ever be called by other server-side functions written by me, and the data being used for `columnName` will be hard-coded in the server-side function. The `accountName`, on the other hand, is user-specified, so it is important that it is in a `cfqueryparam`.

## An Alternate, Safer Solution:

Mark A Kruger [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36485048/getting-a-single-output-from-cfquery-when-query-column-is-cfqueryparam-variable/36485510?noredirect=1#comment60581682_36485510) that it might be a better idea just to select every column you might need and just read the one you're actually interested in. This seems like a pretty good idea. After all, getting every (relevant) column for a record is unlikely to be a much bigger database call than my single column example--unless your database has huge records with tons of columns. You might as well do it this way, and as a side benefit, you wouldn't need to worry about the SQL injections that using a regular coldfusion `#variable#` in a `cfquery` could open you up to.

Reading everyone's answers and comments was very enlightening. Hopefully this question and its answers helps other people who are interested in doing similar things in ColdFusion!

Comment: Yes, I was about to say do not bother with the function :) Much simpler to just return all columns as Mark suggested.  Unless the table contains a bunch of blob columns it is should be that big a deal.

Comment: Agreed. All this work to make the SQL return just one value is kinda pointless since bandwidth is pretty cheap nowadays.

Comment: Plus, the database will probably cache the execution plan more effectively than a bunch of different statements selecting different columns. Especially if you are using cfqueryparam.

Answer (score 3):

A query is a structure of arrays as in queryname[key][1].

It works in the first instance because of backward compatibility. From the beginning you could do queryname.columnname and CF would output the first row of the query for that column. Once you switch to object syntax it no longer works that way.

Try this in your cfreturn:

```
getColumn[columnName][1]
```

Note - you do not need the pound signs in your cfreturn example.

Comment: This method worked after I changed my `columnName` `cfqueryparam` and replaced it with a regular coldfusion variable like `#columnName#`.

Comment: yeah - didn't see that problem in your code sorry. cfqueryparam binds a variable to a primitive "type" - so it's not available to use as a column name.

Comment: Just remember, using the columname in your query like this will open you up to SQL Injection (since I can pass a string that is used directly in your query dynamically). So don't allow any USER input to be passed to the function. In fact, there's no reason not to just select every column anyway and let your cfreturn sort out what you are giving back eh?

Comment: That's a good point. I was trying to minimize the amount of data that the database would have to send, but honestly now that I think about it,  it would only be a few bytes more to return every `role_` column and then just have my function look for the one it is interested in.

Comment: Yeah that's the way to go - just eliminate those attack vectors when you can do it easily. :)